# ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs in Google Analytics SDK

Tags: google-analytics

This issue have been reported for > 1yr ago, and since this is the "official" medium for developers to comment issues I want to move forward
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=667

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService@1f707e41 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3334)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:177)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3317)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:177)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Any solutions?
We are currently using latest google play services